# onTap is recognized as onPanStart MapGesture

Tags: android, here-api

Sometimes when i tap on the map the tap is recognized as `onPanStart`. I need to do something when the user swipes on the map and something different when he taps , but there is no `onSwipe` gesture in the `MapGesture.OnGestureListener`. With using `onPanStart` sometimes the wrong action is called. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating between gestures is somewhat subjective and as a result the parameters are generally tweaked to provide a good UX for the given use case.

Without knowing more about your exact use case, if you want the actions to correspond directly to how the HERE SDK is interpreting the input, then using the callbacks `onPanStart` and `onTapEvent` would be the right thing to do. Note that even though a Pan is technically triggered, it could have such a small velocity that the Map doesn't move much. "Pan" is equivalent to a "Swipe" gesture.

If you do want to tweak the UX a bit, an option would be to write your own Android `GestureDetector` to get the feel you would like (potentially fusing the result with the output of `OnGestureListener` events as well). Alternatively, you could also check that the Map actually moves a certain amount after `onPanStart` is called before triggering your event, perhaps using `Map#OnTransformListener` but this could be tricky to get right.